# Excel changes a string containing the character E to exponential

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I've writen a code in c# to generate from DB table an excel file, however there is a column that has string values some of them are like this: 718E1, and these values excel writes them as exponentials like: 7,18E+03. Can someone help me solve this problem.
Thank you!

I tried :
cellRangC_Prod.EntireColumn.NumberFormat= "@";

However this just writes the cell 718 and it should be 718E1.

Comment: Try formatting your cells/ranges/columns/whatnot as Text format _before_ putting values into them...

Comment: Instead of using Excel Interop use a library like EPPlus or ClosedXML to generate an Excel file directly, without having to install or start Excel. These libraries will take care of storing text as text, even if it looks like a number. With eg EPPlus it's enough to write `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(customers)` to load data from a Customers list into a sheet. There are LoadFromDataTable and LoadFromDataReader methods as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right however I was asked to write the code in the way I did by my senior so I wouldn't change much from previews code written. Thank you though I have risolved the problem now!